# Strapi Async API Request in a Loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, async-await, strapi

I'm using a headless CMS (Strapi), which forces pagination on its GET endpoints, with up to 100 entries per page on the content types. I have ~400 entries on a Location content type that I want to show on the same page. I'm trying to read each page on load and store each Location in an array, but I'm having some issues fetching this data asynchronously. Instead of getting each page, I get the first page for each of the iterations of the loop. I'm new to async-await requests, so I'm not sure how to ensure that I am reading each page's data. Thanks in advance!

```
const getLocationsPage = async (page) => {
    return await useFetch(`${this.config.API_BASE_URL}/api/locations?sort=slug&pagination[page]=${page}&pagination[pageSize]=50`)
}

for(let i = 1; i < this.pageCount; i++){
    const pageResults = await getLocationsPage(i)
    console.log(pageResults)
}
```

Comment: add `pageResults` to data, then use `this.pageResults.concat(await getLocationsPage(i))`, though rather then fetching them all, use/implement pagination, ordering and filtering, noone wants to see 400+ items